# DataGridView cell coloring throws error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagridview

I am currently working on a project that utilizes a DataGridView block to display search results of data that is pulled from a remote MySQL database.

I am trying to re-color the background of each row based on the string value of one of the columns

**The code:**

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.dgvSearchResults.Rows)
            {
                if (row.Cells[4].Value.ToString() == "Outbound")
                {
                    row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightSkyBlue;
                }
                else if (row.Cells[4].Value.ToString() == "Inbound")
                {
                    row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightCyan;
                }
                else
                {
                    row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
                };
            }
```

**My Error:**

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

[image]

I can't seem to figure this one out, any feedback is helpful!

Comment: what event are you doing this in..? is it the OnDataBound event..? can you post the full method that this code resides in..? what line is throwing the object reference error.. did you step thru the code with the debugger or just hit `F5` and go..?

Comment: it is within a DataBindingComplete event, and the screenshot shows the line that it is throwing from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that there are actually at least 5 cells (C# arrays are 0 bound) and make sure `Value` where you call `.ToString()` on is not `null`.
For the latter one you can do the following:

```
if (row.Cells[4].Value != null)
{
    if (row.Cells[4].Value.ToString() == "Outbound")
    {
        row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightSkyBlue;
    }
    else if (row.Cells[4].Value.ToString() == "Inbound")
    {
        row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightCyan;
    }
    else
    {
        row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
    }
}
else
{
    row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
}
```

Comment: This has resolved the issue, I am not sure how the cell is/was null, because there is no null values within the database for any of these fields. (it looks like the very last line in the DataGridView is full null all the way across the board) http://puu.sh/h3EfB/f0d77c8a22.png

Comment: Without looking at the whole program/db structure, query and data I can't even make a guess why that would be the case. Sorry...